# Serving static assets in webpack dev server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I run webpack-dev-server from the root folder of my project.
I have *assets* folder in */src/assets* that is copied by CopyWebPackPlugin:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([ { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' } ])
```

If I put *logo.png* inside assets folder then After running webpack-dev-server I can't access *http://localhost/assets/logo.png* file, but can access *http://localhost/src/assets/logo.png* file. However if I run in production mode the situation turns upside down.

How to configure webpack server to make *http://localhost/assets/logo.png* file accessible in development mode?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can tell webpack to use a different path when loading from the browser.

In the `output` section of your webpack config file add a [`publicPath`](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath) field pointing to your `assets` folder.

**webpack.config.js**

```
output: {
  // your stuff
  publicPath: '/assets/'
}
```

Comment: Can anyone post a full working webpack.config.js? And the version of copy-webpack-plugin they are using?

Comment: This was driving me crazy! Thank you so much for this answer!

Comment: @TonyGutierrez do you still need an example? Happy to share mine.

Comment: btw @TonyGutierrez you can always use create-react-app to create a React application, which you can then eject. The webpack dev/prod configs will be in the config directory. Facebook is good about adding inline notation and keeping those configs up-to-date.

Comment: Then you cant serve a default index.html page at your project root with that configuration.

Comment: @RomainBruckert yeah it seems `web-pack-server` can't see the index.html file

Answer (score 57):

I would add that it was the opposite for me. I originally had my images and `.obj/.mtl` files in a `public` folder that existed at the root of my application. I moved them into an `assets` folder that was created in the `app` folder.

Performing an `npm install --save-dev copy-webpack-plugin` and adding the

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([ { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' } ])
```

to the `webpack.common.js` file fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks, gave me what I needed. In my case, `publicPath` needed to be `/` for my `index.html` file to be built properly but I needed my static files in `/static/`. This sorted it.

Comment: Same here as i was already using publicpath for something else, worked perfectly !

Comment: For the record, YES this plugin DOES work with webpack dev server! The name is slightly confusing because this does not have to literally copy files around.

Answer (score 12):

**Update** (webpack-dev-server 4)

Since the latest version. You have to replace `contentBasePublicPath` and `contentBase` (see original solution below) with `static.directory` and `static.publicPath`. The feature still works.

**webpack.config.js**

```js
{
  devServer: {
    static: { 
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets'), 
      publicPath: '/assets'
    }
  }
}
```

Tested with `webpack 5.58.2`, `webpack-cli 4.9.0`, `webpack-dev-server 4.3.1`.

Keep reading the *Original* solution for further information.

---

**Original** (webpack-dev-server 3)

For everyone who wants real static files without copying them and landed here. The Webpack output configuration `publicPath` does not work.

You need the DevServer property `contentBase` and optional `contentBasePublicPath`.

The documentation really lacks on these properties. So let me explain:

Use case: You want to use static files like videos, sounds and images without copying them.
In this example create a folder `assets` in your project root directory. The rest configuration is default (src, dist).

**webpack.config.js**

```js
{
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets'),
    contentBasePublicPath: '/assets'
  }  
}
```

Without `contentBasePublicPath` the assets are accessible with root URL. Since `contentBase` only defines the folder content.

Example:
Place an image file "test.png" into your assets folder.

Without `contentBasePublicPath` you can access it with e.g. `<img src="test.png">`. With `contentBasePublicPath` you can use `<img src="assets/test.png">`.

```
your-project
|- assets
|  |- test.png
|- dist (...)
|- src (...)
```

You can use any path you want. E.g. move the assets to your src folder. Just place all assets here. It will not be processed / touched by the build. And the app is still loading from the default root (dist) path. This is what we want. The simplest and best solution in my opinion.

Tested with a TypeScript project and Webpack 5 (webpack-cli 4, webpack-dev-server 3).

Comment: This has been changed to the static field now (presumably because they hate us): ```static { directory: resolve_app_path('./example/static'), publicPath: '/static' } }```

Answer (score 10):

You can do:

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    setupMiddlewares: (middlewares, devServer) => {
      devServer.app.use('/assets/', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets')));
      return middlewares;
    }
  }
}
```

My case was to serve files from outside the project root path, and then `CopyWebpackPlugin` felt like the wrong approach.

If you are using webpack-dev-server >=4,<4.7 it's `onBeforeSetupMiddleware` or using v3 it's `devServer.before`.

Comment: Thanks!  This is what helped me.  Easiest solution I found.

Comment: If you use webpack 5 it's `devServer.setupMiddlewares` instead of `devServer.onBeforeSetupMiddleware` ))))

Comment: Can't resolve for ... font face .woff file, .ttf,, .eot though

Comment: Note: it won't resolve for ... font face .woff file, .ttf,, .eot from scss file, but it will work when accessing these assets from the public/index.html file. I suspect the setupMiddlewares for devServer.app.use does not work as it ddid - onBeforeSetup...

Answer (score 3):

i use proxy:

```
proxy: {
  '/static': {
      target: 'http://localhost:3333',
      pathRewrite: {'^/static' : '/app/static'}
   }
}
```

Comment: `this feature is available with react-scripts@0.2.3 and higher.`

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development