# Serve images with Webpack dev server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

How can i to serve my images like static files, not inline them, and not import them?

With my config i can use images in css like i usually do. Bit in html(jsx) i need to import/require every image to work. And i want simply serve my images from `/images` with `webpack-dev-server`.

I have the following configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    './src/index.jsx', // your app's entry point
  ],
  devtool: process.env.WEBPACK_DEVTOOL || 'source-map, eval-source-map',
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./public",
    // do not print bundle build stats
    noInfo: true,
    // enable HMR
    hot: true,
    // embed the webpack-dev-server runtime into the bundle
    inline: true,
    // serve index.html in place of 404 responses to allow HTML5 history
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: PORT,
    host: HOST
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'style.css',
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new DashboardPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/template.html',
      files: {
        css: ['style.css'],
        js: [ "bundle.js"],
      }
    }),
  ]
};
```

Comment: Look at that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870888/serving-static-assets-in-webpack-dev-server