# Can't fetch local file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

It works when I fetch a `tsv` file remotely:

```
// Works well
fetch(
    `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactivemarkets/react-financial-charts/master/packages/stories/src/data/MINUTES.tsv`,
)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => tsvParse(data, parseData()))
    .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
            data,
        });
    })
    .catch(() => {
        this.setState({
            message: `Failed to fetch data.`,
        });
    });
```

However, if I copy this file locally (both in the same directory as the `.tsx` file, as well as in the project's root directory), and replace the argument of the `fetch` function, it doesn't work.

```
// Doesn't work if I change the fetch input to this:
fetch('MINUTES.tsv')

// Also doesn't work
fetch('./MINUTES.tsv')
```

I get this error in the console output:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/minutes.tsv 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: `fetch` uses HTTP protocol. Add more context for the problem.

Comment: @AdamAzad I added some info. I'm trying to parse the file. The first code block pulls the file from remote and then parses. I'm trying to do the same for my local `tsv` file instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your `tsv` file to the `public` folder of your project if you're using `create-react-app` for example. If you're not. You need to serve that file for it to be available for the `fetch`

Please, check this [question/aswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64195120/10415577)

Comment: I'm using typescript with webpack. By `public` folder, do you mean `node_modules`?

Comment: No he means a folder named ```public``` inside your react project

Comment: Where do you keep your favicon for example? `public` folder is usually on the same level like `node_modules`. Public folder serves `static` assets/content like icons, images, maybe some global css. Files in `public` folder are accessible by URL directly .

Comment: To serve static content via webpack, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34900495/10415577)

Comment: @Luka I followed that answer but it didn't work. I added `publicPath: '/assets/'` to the correct location in my webpack config. Then I created an `assets` folder with `MINUTES.tsv`. I tried to put the `assets` folder both in my root project directory as well as in the `src` directory. Then I did `fetch('assets/MINUTES.tsv')` in my code, but I still get the 404 error that it can't find the file `http://localhost:9000/assets/minutes.tsv`  @DanielOlsen

Comment: Have you tried loading `http://localhost:9000/assets/minutes.tsv` directly via your browser? You need to make sure that's working and only after that you can continue playing with the `fetch` itself.

Comment: @Luka Typing that into my browser and I see the text message on the screen "Cannot GET /assets/minutes.tsv"

Comment: Where did you put your `webpack.config.js` file? You should keep that file in the root of the project. Also, `public` folder should be on the same level like `webpack.config.js`

Comment: @Luka I put my `webpack.config.js` in the root folder of the project (next to `package.json` and `tsconfig.json`). I have a `src` folder there too. Inside that `src` folder, I have my  `index.tsx` and `index.html`. My entry inside my webpack config is `"./src/index.tsx"`. I've tried putting my `assets` folder *both* in my root project folder, *and* in my `src` folder. Neither approach has worked yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234725/discussion-between-luka-and-jase).