# How to proxy static files with wepack devserver?

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, webpack-dev-server, prerender

My `publicPath` is `/static/dist`. How i can proxy `static/dist` to `/` when my dev server running?

I know i can:

```
let publicPath;
if (process.env.NODE_BUILD_DEPLOYMENT_PATH) {
    // Change process.env.NODE_BUILD_DEPLOYMENT_PATH to match the path to your files
    // in production (could be S3, CloudFront, etc.)
    publicPath = process.env.NODE_BUILD_DEPLOYMENT_PATH;
} else {
    publicPath = 'http://localhost:8099/';
}
```

But i need proxy. It's for pre-render. After render i need  `static/dist` prefix for all my static files. But when my dev server running i want proxy `static/dist` to `/`.

For example: `static/dist/js` -> `/js`.

Comment: I tried [devServer.before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67435323/2205911), I use `"@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.0"`, finally work code is: `const serveStatic = require('express-static');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        ...
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/67435323/2205911
        // 前端直接映射任意静态目录，就像nginx一样，不再依赖后端
        before: (middlewares, devServer) => {
            devServer.app.use('/assets/', serveStatic('/home/snp/vue-static'));
            return middlewares;
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
        server: {
            port: options.devServer.port,
            proxy: {
                '/static/dist/*': {
                    target: 'http://localhost:8099',
                    pathRewrite: {'^/static/dist/': ''}
                }
            }
        },
```